# How to predict single values in R

Tags: regression

I have a linear regression model with two variables meanValuesHeatingPower and meanValuesOutsideTemperature that both have 365 entries. Now I want to use this linear model to predict only 1 value (in this case this value is 1)). If I use the following code, the desired value in not printed but 365 values. Furthermore I get the error message:
"Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 365 rows "

```
linearModel<-lm(meanValuesHeatingPower~meanValuesOutsideTemperature)
    pred<-predict(linearModel, data.frame(train_x = c(1)))
    print(pred)
```

What I want is quite simple. With the regression I get a linear function:
y(x)=mx+c and I want to calculate the value of the function for x=1.

How can I get that value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the incorrect X variable name in your call to `predict` (it should be called the same as the X variable you used when you created the initial model)

Although not necessary, its typical to have `meanValuesHeatingPower` and `meanValuesOutsideTemperature` as columns in the same dataframe, and then pass that dataframe in to `data` when creating the model

The following works for me:

```
df <- data.frame(meanValuesHeatingPower = c(1,4,3,7), 
                 meanValuesOutsideTemperature = c(4,3,4,7))

linearModel<-lm(meanValuesHeatingPower ~ meanValuesOutsideTemperature, data = df)

pred<-predict(linearModel, data.frame(meanValuesOutsideTemperature = c(1)))
print(pred)
```